# When updating a text file via code, is the entire file re-saved, or just the parts?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Okay so my overall goal is to create a UWP notes app that doesn't require the end-user to manually save each note they write; this would be done automatically for them.

So what I'm looking to do is create a C# class that will detect changes to the document the user is currently writing and constantly update the underlying text file (This will eventually be written to a row within the database, but I hear it is less efficient to constantly update records within a DB than to deal with text files for this matter?).

But yeah, this is pretty much what apps like OneNote do in the background for the user, and so the user have to never worry about saving the file or losing data in situations where the computer loses power or the app terminates unexpectedly.

So if I created a class that detected changes to the document and then update the underlying file, is the WHOLE file rewritten or just the particular parts (bytes?) that were changed within (or appended to) the text?

I'm just looking for the most efficient way to constantly update a file because if a user is a fast typist, the system will have to be able to keep up with every single keystroke input.

Last, would the entire file have to be rewritten if the user makes random changes to the text at random locations (rather than append to the end of the file)? Does any of this even make sense. I tend to write a lot to ask a simple question. I have problems....

Answer (score 0):

I would do a timertick event and have it automatically save every 3 to 5 seconds.  I do this alot. I understand what your doing, but automatically saving every key stroke, would be putting a lot of stress on the program.

I would automatically save every few seconds on a if basis,

If a change is detected then it will save. Think about this answer, it hs been saved almost 100 times if done by keystroke.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. And yes, that actually makes more sense. I guess I never considered it because I never heard of a timetick class, but it is worth investigating. Thx, again.

Comment: Go to your toolbox and create a timer. In the timertick in the code put what you want updated or saved. I use this alot because I forget to save things in my app. So I have it save every few seconds then I also have it update the file in the same timer. So when I close the app and reopen it. Everything is the way I want it.